# Distance from Chicago to New York vs Distance between Chicago and New York

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

- > Distance from Chicago to New York is 1500 km.
- > Distance between Chicago and New York is 1500 km.

Are these 2 sentences exactly the same or they have different meanings?
Can I use them interchangeably?

Comment: We would say *the distance* in both sentences, and the actual distance is ~1150 km.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements mean the same in terms of stating a distance.

However

> Distance **between** Chicago and New York is 1500 km.

is a more neutral toned way of stating how far apart Chicago and New York are

> Distance **from** Chicago to New York is 1500 km.

would usually be used to place the centre of measurement using Chicago as the **origin**

> The distance **from** the sun.
>   Distances to London are measured **from** Charing Cross.

This is in contrast to using **to** to show the **objective** or **destination**

> The road **to** Damascus
>   The long road **to** freedom

Comment: I remembered in my school days years back I wrote similar sentence with **the distance from A to B**, but I ended up getting a red strike-through, and a correction - **the distance between A and B**.